# Как задать путь к контроллеру правильно?

Tags: php, php-frameworks, kohana

Есть контроллер с выводом

```
public function action_first(){
 //пока что не использую ввид,в будущем код будет подключен через загрузку вида...   
echo '<a href="mycontroller/index3">Перейти на страницу регистрации </a>';
}
```

Вызываю **http://localhost/kohana/myconstroller/first** вид прекрасно выводится...

Перехожу по ссылке получаю запрос к **http://localhost/kohana/myconstroller/myconstroller/index3**  а хочу **http://localhost/kohana/myconstroller/index3**

Помогите мне справится..
Как аналогично вызывать загрузку другого контроллера - **http://localhost/kohana/other/action** с этого URL ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<a href="mycontroller/index3">
```

Относительная же ссылка. Сделайте `/mycontroller/index3` или `URL::base().'mycontroller/index3'`
На будущее, почитайте про `Route::url()`

Comment: /mycontroller/index3 -так не помогло...Да оно переходит на http://localhost/my/index3 ,но у меня нужно так http://localhost/kohana/my/index3 .Eсли задать kohana/my/index3 то преходит на http://localhost/kohana/my/kohana/my/index3 . А вот URL::base() сработал...Благодарен...Почитаю ,то что вы посоветовали...Вы мне очень помогаете в изучении фреймворка.Благодарен.

Comment: О, я не обратил внимание, что у вас ``/kohana/``, соответственно, ссылка должна была бы быть ``/kohana/mycontroller/index3``. Но это **неправильно**, т.к. в будущем ``base_url`` может измениться.

Comment: Отличное объяснение..:Жаль что не могу проголосовать 100 раз.

Comment: :) изучайте

Answer (score 2):

а лучше используйте класс Html и делайте ссылки так

```
Html::anchor($link, $text, array $attributes);
```

Comment: Да.Логично.